# About const and thread-safety of "pure" function objects

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, constants

In my program, there are "functions" taking appropriate arguments, perform some computations, and return corresponding results. These "functions" have some internal states which are not externally visible; they are mainly memory buffers for temporary results. That means, those "functions" do not have any logical states.

Those memory buffers and other things are actually changing from each call to call, as the required buffer size may change depending on the input data.

Although those buffers are just for temporaries, I need to control their lifetime, constructing/destructing threads, etc.. And I don't want those temporaries to be supplied from the call site because their use is just internal to "functions". So I think those "functions" need to be implemented in terms of class (rather than function with/without static variables).

Since there is no externally visible state change (although there are states that are given and never change after the construction), I think it is better to qualify the function (I mean, the function call operator or whatever) with `const`. But then I'm not sure how should I deal with thread-safety of these temporary resources, because as well-known, in C++11, `const` by default implies thread-safety.

Currently the uses of functions are mainly single-threaded; there are only rare situations where instances of these functions are shared by several threads, so I externally locked the calls when really necessary. (More precisely, there is a lock guarding the whole series of computations. When another thread wants to perform a computation, it obtains that lock. There is currently no lock associated to each function.)

Implementations of the functions are separated from the outside, because I planned to use them in other projects.

Is it better to guard the computations with locks inside the implementations of functions? Or just leave the functions non-const although they are just (at least conceptually) pure functions? Or just mark them as `const` although they are not thread-safe (so are not really "const")? Or should I consider a different approach?

Comment: A `const` qualified member function only means that it can be called on a `const` qualified object. It has nothing to do with thread-safety.

Comment: Use `static thread_local char buffer[];`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude afaik, not since c++11 *and* if you want your type to work with the standard library; the standard library poses further requirements on const member functions re to thread-safety ...

Comment: If there is no logical state, why isn't the temporary buffer just local variables? Or heap memory bound to local variables?

Comment: @PasserBy Although not specified in the question, I assume the answer is to avoid the cost of allocation/deallocation at each call.

Comment: @PasserBy As sbabbi pointed out, allocation/deallocation costs are quite large and can't be neglected. I need more fine-grained control on lifetime of temporaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a `thread_local` buffer.

```
int T::myfunction(int arg) const
{
    static thread_local U mybuffer;
    // impl...
}
```

`thread_local` will give you thread safety, as each thread will use its own buffer. Since it is `static` inside a function, the buffer will be retained after each function call.

Comment: This is really a reasonable approach, but I have several concerns. First, temporaries are in fact quite precious resources (e.g., GPU memory), so I want to minimize their usage; it seems to be too wasteful if I should allocate another set of temporaries just for threads that rarely use them. Second and more importantly, it is critical to control the lifetime of temporaries, partially because temporary resources are not very abundant. In my application, it should be possible to destroy all the temporaries at a desired timing by e.g., destructing the function object. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `U` can be an handle to a buffer, with a non trivial constructor/destructor.
When a thread gets created, `U` constructor can query a resource manager to retrieve a dedicated buffer (possibly passed via an argument to the constructor). Conversely, when a thread exits, the runtime will call `U` destructor freeing its resources.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm back so late. I think things might become complicated because I want ````mybuffer```` to be all released when the destructor of ````T```` is called, but I can imagine some ways to resolve all the issues. Perhaps it's better to just let ````myfunction```` non-const, though. Anyway, thanks!